# How can perform the check availability in Sabre API?

Tags: api, rest, sabre

According to [Sabre API documentation](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/search/revalidate_itinerary/reference-documentation), to revalidate a list of itineraries (check availability), I need to perform an HTTPS request to the endpoint `/v4/shop/flights/revalidate`.

By looking at their swagger documentation, to check one itinerary, with 1 ADT passenger, I do the following request:

```
{
      OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ: {
        OriginDestinationInformation: [
          {
            DepartureDateTime: '2023-06-02T18:30:00',
            OriginLocation: {
              LocationCode: 'JFK',
            },
            DestinationLocation: {
              LocationCode: 'CDG',
            },
            RPH: '1',
            TPA_Extensions: {
              SegmentType: {
                Code: 'O',
              },
              Flight: [
                {
                  Number: 7,
                  DepartureDateTime: '2023-06-02T18:30:00',
                  ArrivalDateTime: '2023-06-03T08:00:00',
                  Type: 'A',
                  ClassOfService: 'C',
                  OriginLocation: {
                    LocationCode: 'JFK',
                  },
                  DestinationLocation: {
                    LocationCode: 'CDG',
                  },
                  Airline: {
                    Operating: 'AF',
                    Marketing: 'AF',
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
        POS: {
          Source: [
            {
              PseudoCityCode: 'XXXX',
              RequestorID: {
                CompanyName: {
                  Code: 'TN',
                },
                ID: '1',
                Type: '1',
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        TPA_Extensions: {
          IntelliSellTransaction: {
            RequestType: {
              Name: '50ITINS',
            },
          },
        },
        TravelPreferences: {
          TPA_Extensions: {
            VerificationItinCallLogic: {
              Value: 'B',
            },
          },
        },
        TravelerInfoSummary: {
          SeatsRequested: [1],
          AirTravelerAvail: [
            {
              AirTraveler: {
                PassengerTypeQuantity: {
                  Code: 'ADT',
                  Quantity: 1,
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        Version: '4',
      },
    }
```

But I get an error:

`Invalid request. It is not compliant with schema. 1871\nElement '{http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05}AirTraveler': This element is not expected. Expected is ( {http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05}PassengerTypeQuantity ).`

According to Sabre Swagger documentation, my request is correct, but I get this error.
Is the swagger documentation wrong or I do something wrong?

According to Swagger documentation, the object `AirTravelerAvail` contains an array of objects with the property `AirTraveler`, but according to their request example, the property `AirTraveler` is not expected. Why?

I try to perform a revalidate flight request to Sabre REST API with the query parameters indicated in their Swagger documentation, and get a valid response.
But actually I get a validation error.